# Deleted Partition Recovery Into System

Tags: boot, partitioning, data-recovery

I was installing ubuntu 22.04 on my system. There were 4 partitions on my system and I selected one of the four partition for the installation and chose the option of resizing the partition. Initially my partition was of size 20GB and The partition not selected and ubuntu installed in another drive partition . there was I have very important data got deleted,

Now the data that I have lost is meant a lot to me and I want to recover that drive data. So is there any way I can recover it?  . please please help me to get out of this problem..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)